# Stuck in a while loop; calc days between two dates

Tags: java, date, while-loop

I've actually been browsing for quite a while on this site, sadly without much progress. Thanks to a lot of extremely useful answers, I've learned quite a bunch of stuff though!

I'm learning Java since ... about 4 days (I guess?) so I'm not very experienced in the methods I can use.

There's this assignment we got at our univ. We shall write a program that returns how many days have passed between two dates. The only restriction is to keep the program as simple as possible, we're not allowed to use "complicated methods".
Sadly, my program is kind of stuck. If I try it out e.g. the dates 23 01 1994 and 07 04 1997, it counts only up to 01 01 1997 and suddenly stops. I have no idea why that happens, I even doubt if I fully understood what I wrote there.

Anyways, here's my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Datecalc {

public static int yearcounter,monthcounter,daycounter,days;

public static int[] input() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Eingabe der Daten
    String day1 = input.next();
    String month1 = input.next();
    String year1 = input.next();

    String day2 = input.next();
    String month2 = input.next();
    String year2 = input.next();


    int day1int = Integer.parseInt(day1);
    int month1int = Integer.parseInt(month1);
    int year1int = Integer.parseInt(year1);

    int day2int = Integer.parseInt(day2);
    int month2int = Integer.parseInt(month2);
    int year2int = Integer.parseInt(year2);

    int [] eingabe = new int [6];

        eingabe[0] = day1int;
        eingabe[1] = month1int;
        eingabe[2] = year1int;

        eingabe[3] = day2int;
        eingabe[4] = month2int;
        eingabe[5] = year2int;

    return eingabe; 

// put everything into an array to be able to use it in the main method

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] eingabe = input();

    days=0;

    daycounter = eingabe[0];
    monthcounter = eingabe[1];
    yearcounter = eingabe[2];

    Integer[] einunddreissig = {1,3,5,7,8,10,12}; //months with 31 days
    Integer[] dreissig = {4,6,9,11}; // months with 30 days

    while (daycounter != eingabe[3] && monthcounter != eingabe[4] && yearcounter != eingabe[5] ) {

        // if its a month that has 31 days
        if ( Arrays.asList(einunddreissig).contains(monthcounter) ) {

            for (int i = daycounter; i <= 31; i++) {
                days++;
            }
                daycounter=1;
                monthcounter++;


        } 

        // if its a month with 30 days
        if ( Arrays.asList(dreissig).contains(monthcounter) ) {
            for (int i = daycounter; i <= 30; i++) {
                days++;
                daycounter++;                   
            }
                daycounter=1;
                monthcounter++;

        // february     
        } else if ( monthcounter == 2) {
            for (int i = daycounter; i <= 28; i++) {
                days++;
            }
                daycounter=1;
                monthcounter++;

        } else if (monthcounter==13) {
            monthcounter=1;
            yearcounter++;
        }
    }

        // checking how many days were counted and comparing the input (eingabe[something]) to how far the daycounter reached
        System.out.println(" "+days);
        System.out.println(" "+daycounter+" "+monthcounter+" "+yearcounter);
        System.out.println(eingabe[3]+" "+eingabe[4]+" "+eingabe[5]);
}
}
```

I hope there is somebody who might be so kind to give me a hint how to fix that.

Comment: you dont need a for-loop to add 31 days, just 'days += 31'

Comment: By the way, if you truly need to do some date and time math, use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library rather than do your own math. If you are just practicing your Java, then continue the fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate this out into two different functions, one that counts the days until the end of the current year and another which counts the days since the beginning of the current year. Then you can put the total days in terms of those values.

First write a generic `sum()` function:

```
public static int sum(int[] a, int start, int end){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = start; i < end; i++) sum += a[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Then use the `sum()` function to easily compute `daysToEnd` and `daysFromStart`:

```
static int[] daysInMonth = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

public static int daysToEnd(int day, int month){
    return sum(daysInMonth, month - 1, 12) - day;
}

public static int daysFromStart(int day, int month){
    return sum(daysInMonth, 0, month - 1) + day;
}

public static void main(String... args){
    int[] date1 = {23, 1, 1994};
    int[] date2 = {1, 1, 1997};

    // This actually works for same or different years
    int days = daysToEnd(date1[0], date1[1]) +
               365*(date2[2] - date1[2] - 1) +
               daysFromStart(date2[0], date2[1]);

    System.out.println(days);
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood what you were trying to do at first. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Wow that's really easy to understand.
I didn't know about the daysFromStart/daysToEnd method before.
I guess in case the solution above isn't valid, THIS is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There's something I can't understand.
If we for example have date1={1,1,1997} and date2={23,2,1997} it will go through daysFromStart with day=23 and month=2. days=23 adding daysInMonth[2 - 1] on top which is 28, because the second entry of the daysInMonth array is 28!?!
But it's actually 31... What's the error in my thinking??

Comment: for {23,2,1997} you actually have days = 23 + daysInMonth[1-1]. The --month in the while loop subtracts 1 before it executes the next line.

Comment: Also, the if-else actually wasn't needed. It turns out the statement I had for non-same years works even if the years are the same, so now the code is actually very short.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use loops?  Here's some food for thought -- imagine this as a simple algebra problem.  In your program, each date is modeled as a collection of quantities, each of a different unit.  Once you obtain uniform units, you can just do the arithmetic.

In the UNIX world we use an agreed-upon reference date called the "epoch", 12:00 AM on 01 January, 1970 as a reference date.  Kind of like "tare" on a balance.  All other dates can be represented as some number of seconds relative to that time.

Comment: Hmmm... but our program has to work for the date of 01/01/1901 to 12/31/2099. Would it still be possible to use the reference date in that case?

Comment: Yes, dates prior to the epoch can be represented by negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would construct the passed in user input to java.util.Date type. But I am assuming line by line input. You can construct a string using StringBuilder if you want to get day,mth,year separately.

```
try{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");

  System.out.println("Enter Date1");

  String dateSt1= br.readLine();       // Accepts date1 as string 

  System.out.println("Enter Date2");  

  String dateSt2= br.readLine();  // Accepts date2 as string 

  Date date1=df.parse(dateSt1);     // Date String to Date
  Date date2=df.parse(dateSt2);
}catch(IOException ex)
}catch(ParseExceptionOfSomesort pex)
}
```

then use this to get the difference in days -

```
int diffInDays = (int)( (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) 
             / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) )
```

If you get this in negative, that means the second date is before first date.

Think: Do I have to do it using a loop or hasn't java already added some utility method to do date compare?

What makes something "complicated" though? Writing too many lines of code or using existing java library?

Comment: I get what you mean. Using existing libraries doesnt make it more complicated, rather the opposite. The problem is the 'restrictions' given in the assignment. They dont really tell what we are allowed to use because they assume we are not that good in Java.
Quote "You're allowed to import classes for date inputs only". What does that mean regarding the code above?? Valid or not?

Your solution worked awesome though. I will email my version of it to my tutor just to check if they accept this method as a solution.
If not, I will have to stick to If, While, and For... which is crap.

Comment: I understand what you mean. If it is question on loop, you can't answer it a different way, unless it is a trick question.

Comment: This is the more correct (will take leap years into account) and efficient way to do it; however, it's a little advanced for only 4 days of learning Java.